# What would be the best approach to porting MAME or SCUMMVM to .NET (XNA or Silverlight)?

Tags: .net, xna, emulation

I wonder what are the main challenges to porting those emulator engines.

Could there been any sucess without having to rewrite all the code? Any conversion tools available that can help?

Answer (score 1):

Some people have tried but it seems they [gave up](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=1011253&SiteID=1):

[scummvmxna](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scummvmxna/)

Other route could be the approach taken by [Cibyl](http://spel.bth.se/index.php/Cibyl).

Answer (score 0):

There is some people over at XDA developers that is making a DLL wrapper for C#.Net/XNA/Silverlight... The DllImport Project:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1006331

As I understand it this is for wrapping DLLs to use them on Windows Phone 7 systems

But I don't know if it will be possible to use it for ScummVM. It seems like you can't do p/invoke. And as I understand ScummVM is heavily dependent on p/invoke.
http://forums.scummvm.org/viewtopic.php?t=9350&sid=d324c805f27e3c62713f02db3763c021

NOTE: I haven't been reading up on this much at all... I was just browsing around, searching for the possibility if ScummVM will ever be released for WP7 units, and found this question and thought I ought to answer what I've found out. I can have misunderstood some of the things I been reading. So just check it out for yourself if you are interested in trying to port or wrap the ScummVM libraries to C#.Net/XNA/Silverlight code.

God I'm tired... I should really go to sleep now...